# Error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I start eclipse I get the following error:

[image]

What does it mean?

Also next I get this screen

[image]

Now what does it mean?

NOTE: The hyperlink pages won't open and are giving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is telling you about missing library.
To install, Type in terminal:
`sudo apt-get install subversion` 
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn`

To install from eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php

To install Subversion-1.8: 
Remove your existing libsvn-java:
`sudo apt-get purge libsvn-java` 
 
Then, add the following software source and re-install:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dominik-stadler/subversion-1.8` 
`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get install libsvn-java`

**Edited**
You can download [subversion_1.8.13 deb file](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/216677395/subversion_1.8.13-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) and install it.
For more versions:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/subversion

Comment: And what about first error?

Comment: The above mentioned repository doesn't work for ubuntu xenial, any other way out?

Comment: That repository doesn't work in xenial as well. Any more ideas?

Comment: I tried to download and install but it says `A later version is already installed` Is it alright? Or do I need the downgraded version for the said error? Anyway thanks for the effort.